# No issues showing as Active in SP

Tags: sharepoint-email

I have created an issue log (renamed to "Action Items" in SP 2013.  When trying to set up alerts, it is allowing a selection of either "My Issues or "Active Issues".   My Action item list when filtered to Active Issues is blank.  Does there have to be an Issue status set for Active for this to occur?  I don't have a status that is "Active".  In addition, this does not make sense to me as the only status I would not like an alert for is Closed. Can anyone help?